# How to not return result from Stored Procudure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a problem, i have stored procedure, which returns result, and also i'm using this procedure inside another procedure in cursor to insert some data in tables, but this procedure which using in cursor returns data, but i don't need it exclusively in this situation. I need just result from procedure which calling this procedure.

First Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyInterface]
( 
    @intercafeId int,
    @processIdPrefix nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
    @newInterfaceId int

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

....
some code
....


        DECLARE @taskIdsToCopy table (interfacetaskid int NOT NULL)

        INSERT INTO @taskIdsToCopy(interfacetaskid)
        SELECT interfacetaskid FROM icinterfacetask
        WHERE interfaceid = @intercafeId


        DECLARE @taskIdForCursor int
        DECLARE @newTaskId TABLE (id int)
        DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
            select interfacetaskid from @taskIdsToCopy


        OPEN cur
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @taskIdForCursor
        
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

                EXEC CopyTask @taskIdForCursor, @newInterfaceId
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @taskIdForCursor
        END
        CLOSE cur
        DEALLOCATE cur
    
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SELECT @newInterfaceId;

END
```

Second procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyTask] 
    @taskid int, 
    @destinationinterfaceid int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @newTaskIds table (id int NOT NULL)
    DECLARE @stepIdsToCopy table (id int NOT NULL)
...
some code
...

        declare @newId int = (select top 1 id from @newTaskIds);


        INSERT INTO @stepIdsToCopy(id)
        SELECT schemastepid FROM icschemastep
        WHERE interfacetaskid = @taskid

        DECLARE @stepIdForCursor int
        DECLARE @newStepIds TABLE (id int)
        DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
            select id from @stepIdsToCopy

        OPEN cur
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @stepIdForCursor

        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @newStepIds
                EXEC dbo.CopyStep @stepIdForCursor, @newId
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @stepIdForCursor
        END
        CLOSE cur
        DEALLOCATE cur

    
    ;with cte as (
    select steptar.schemasteporder oldorder, steptar.schemastepid oldid
        from icschemastep as steptar
            inner join icinterfacetask as tasktar on tasktar.interfacetaskid = steptar.interfacetaskid
            inner join icschemastep as stepsour on stepsour.dataproviderid = steptar.schemastepid
            inner join icinterfacetask as tasksour on tasksour.interfacetaskid = stepsour.interfacetaskid
        where  tasksour.interfacetaskid = @taskid
        and stepsour.steptype = 10 
        )
        select steptar.schemastepid as newstepforgoto, cte.oldid as oldid
            into #newgotosteps  
                from icschemastep as steptar
                    inner join cte as cte on cte.oldorder = steptar.schemasteporder
                where steptar.interfacetaskid = @newId

    update steptar
        set
            dataproviderid = new.newstepforgoto
        from icschemastep as steptar
            inner join icschemastep as stepsour on stepsour.schemasteporder = steptar.schemasteporder
            inner join icschemastep as oldstep on oldstep.schemastepid = steptar.dataproviderid
            inner join #newgotosteps as new on new.oldid = steptar.dataproviderid
        where stepsour.interfacetaskid = @taskid and steptar.interfacetaskid = @newId
        
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    
    SELECT @newId 
END
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Don't post links to off site resources for code; include the relevant code in the question. As for the question, you can't. If you don't want a procedure to return a dataset, don't have a `SELECT` in it that does return one.

Comment: All these cursors and nested sprocs look very exciting, but three bets the whole thing can be done in about 2 statements

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, I'd suggest you try output parameters. One or more of these ought to satisfy what you're looking for. Microsoft [has a good document available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15) on how they work, including how to deal with it inside code examples.

Comment: Not exactly, i won't return result from second procedure, just in case of using by another procedure. But still need it if i will use just this procedure in code for example.

Comment: Perhaps you should add an (optional) parameter to the proc, that stops the returning of the dataset when a value for that parameter is passed, @Taifunov . You'll going to need to `ALTER` the procedure in some way, regardless.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks yep, i think this is the best choise